# MS vs Non-MS C++ compiler compatibility

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw

Thinking of using MinGW as an alternative to VC++ on Windows, but am worried about compatibility issues. I am thinking in terms of behaviour, performance on Windows (any chance a MinGW compiled EXE might act up). Also, in terms of calling the Windows API, third-party DLLs, generatic and using compatible static libraries, and other issues encountered with mixing parts of the same application with the two compilers.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere? Do you wish to know the general differences? Do you intend to mix msvc-dlls with mingw-libs?

Comment: The 90% odds are that this will reveal bugs in *your* code.  The accidental UB kind.

Comment: @Andre, the question is how reliable is doing something like this? I am worried about how compliant the MinGW compiler is.

Comment: All questions were answered by both answer -- will pick one

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, MinGW is not a compiler, but an environment, it is bundled with gcc.

If you think of using `gcc` to compile code and have it call the Windows API, it's okay as it's C; but for C++ DLLs generated by MSVC, you might have a harsh wake-up call.

The main issue is that in C++, each compiler has its own name mangling (or more generally ABI) and its own Standard library. You cannot mix two different ABI or two different Standard Libraries. End of the story.

Clang has a specific MSVC compatibility mode, allowing it to accept code that MSVC accepts *and* to emit code that is binary compatible with code compiled with MSVC. Indeed, it is even [officially supported in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/).

Obviously, you could also simply do the cross-DLL communication in C to circumvent most issues.

*EDIT*: Kerrek's clarification.

Comment: Just to clarify, "Windows API and Windows DLL" all use a pure C interface and ABI and work very well with MingW/GCC. In fact, there's a winapi package for MingW that provides pretty comprehensive support for the Windows API *and* DirectX (8 and 9 I think). MFC is a separate issue, of course, but at least as far as Windows API programming is concerned, MingW is worth a shot.

Comment: @Kerrek: Thanks, I have amended the text to reflect the difference between the Windows provided ABI and C++ libraries compiled for Windows as those are different beasts.

Comment: Got it! MinGW-GCC & VC++ are ABI incompatible. C-only interfaces are guaranteed to work. Any idea if Microsoft documents its VC++ ABI? Thanks for the "clang" tip.

Comment: @Nick: I think it is quite well documented, and that's how Clang is gradully moving to full support. However the issue is that the Structured Exceptions are patented I think, which prevent Clang from generating perfectly compatible code.

Comment: Thanks, I must give Clang a try.

Comment: I recall some newer APIs were missing from the mingw WINAPI headers, but I got around by loading the dlls dynamically and "GetProcAddress-ing".

Comment: @Tamás: You can do that or simply regenerate the `A` archive and add a declaration of the function to the appropriate w32api header.

Comment: Sure, but I felt it was safer to keep my code in the project (if someone else checks out the source, they would have to do the same to be able to compile).

Comment: If you run into WinAPI not present on mingw, try mingw-w64, which provide a much more complete implementation.

Comment: @rubenvb: I always assumed (from the name) that mingw-w64 was for 64bits code generation ?

Comment: Matthieu M.: it is a completely independently developed alternative, which had as one of its goals to *also* support Win64, which partly explains the name. There's even multilib toolchains possible (like on Linux), but they're a pest to use without autotools, so most builds don't do multilib.

Comment: Would the answer change if the OP replaced `C++` with `C`?

Comment: @Royi: Somewhat. Each OS defines its own C ABI, so there is still some variance, however said C ABI is much simpler than the C++ ABI. I should also revise the answer to indicate that Clang has improved a lot with regard to MSVC compatibility; I am not sure whether it is 100% compatible, but if not it certainly is close.

Comment: I wonder if static `C` libraries compiled with GCC (MinGW64) or Clang (Under MinGW64 and not MS Driver) are guaranteed to be compatible with MSVC.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to compile a large amount of C++ code developed for VC++ with the MinGW toolchain;  however, the ease with which you complete this task depends significantly on how C++-standards-compliant the code is.

If the C++ code utilizes VC++ extensions, such as [`__uuidof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaah6a61.aspx), then you will need to rewrite these portions.

You won't be able to compile ATL & MFC code with MinGW because the ATL & MFC headers utilize a number of VC++ extensions and depend on VC++-specific behaviors:

- [`try`-`except` Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- `__uuidof`
- [`throw(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wfa0edys%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- Calling a function without forward-declaring it.
- [`__declspec(nothrow)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/49147z04.aspx)
- ...

You won't be able to use VC++-generated `LIB` files, so you can't use MinGW's linker, `ld`, to link static libraries without recompiling the library code as a MinGW `A` archive.

You *can* link with closed-source DLLs; however, you will need to [export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) the symbols of the DLL as a [`DEF` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [use `dlltool`](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html) to make the corresponding `A` archive (similar to the VC++ `LIB` file for each DLL).

MinGW's inclusion of the w32api project basically means that code using the Windows C API will compile just fine, although some of the newer functions may not be immediately available. For example, a few months ago I was having trouble compiling code that used some of the "secure" functions (the ones with the `_s` suffix), but I got around this problem by exporting the symbols of the DLL as a `DEF`, preparing an up-to-date `A` archive, and writing forward declarations.

In some cases, you will need to adjust the arguments to the MinGW preprocessor, `cpp`, to make sure that all header files are properly included and that certain macros are predefined correctly.

What I recommend is just trying it. You will definitely encounter problems, but you can usually find a solution to each by searching on the Internet or asking someone. If for no other reason, you should try it to learn more about C++, differences between compilers, and what standards-compliant code is.

Comment: Interesting information, I found more on MinGW and DLLs here: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs

Comment: @Nick: One quick note: you may have trouble using `pexports`. It would always crash when I attempted to use it to generate a `DEF` for one of the Windows DLLs (I can't remember which one).

Comment: I just tried `pexports` on a recently VC9 generated DLL and it worked flawlessly. Thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: Would the answer change if the OP replaced `C++` with `C`?