# SFML undefined reference even with defining libs

Tags: c++, makefile, sfml

I tried to install SFML library to VS Code project using a Makefile. But I am faced with a problem. I have the following code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Creating the main window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Asteroids");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And I have the following Makefile:

```
CXX       := g++
CXX_FLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -ggdb

BIN     := bin
SRC     := src
INCLUDE := include
LIB     := lib

LIBRARIES   := -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio -lsfml-main

EXECUTABLE  := main

SFML_LIBRARY := "C:\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\include"
SFML_LIB := "C:\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\lib"

all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

run: clean all
    cls
    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) -L$(LIB) -I$(SFML_LIBRARY) -L$(SFML_LIB) $^ -o $@ $(LIBRARIES)

clean:
    -del $(BIN)\* /Q
```

But when I try to compile the code, I get the following error message:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -ggdb -Iinclude -Llib -I"C:\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\include" -L"C:\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\lib" src/main.cpp -o bin/main -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio -lsfml-main
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\totalboy\AppData\Local\Temp\cclPlFnI.o:D:\C++ Projects\Asteroids/src/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\totalboy\AppData\Local\Temp\cclPlFnI.o: in function `main':
D:\C++ Projects\Asteroids/src/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\C++ Projects\Asteroids/src/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\C++ Projects\Asteroids/src/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:23: bin/main] Error 1
```

Libs:

[image]

So, can somebody tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you receive can be attributed to the compilers you are using and used for compiling the SFML libraries you currently have. There are differences in the C++ ABI across compilers (and even across versions of the same compiler) <sup>[1]</sup>. When you want to link your code to a library, you have to make sure that the compiler you use and the one used with the library are the same, or are ABI-compatible.

When using `vcpkg` to download libraries, the source of those libraries are the ones that are actually downloaded and not the library itself. The source is then compiled "using the most recent version of Visual Studio that it could find <sup>[2]</sup>. Thus, if you want to use libraries downloaded via `vcpkg` in Windows, like in your case, you have to use Visual Studio, or, at least just the compiler, MSVC. So, a fix for your problem is to use MSVC (provided by Visual Studio), instead of the compiler in MinGW, which is usually GCC.

If you still want to use MinGW, there are two options:

1. The simplest option is to use MinGW-compatible SFML packages. There are official pre-built packages for MinGW over the SFML website. Note that these MinGW packages are only compatible with GCC 7.3.0 (at the time of writing). If you are using a different version or a different compiler, you have to resort to option 2.
2. Another option is to compile SFML on your own first. Once you have finished compiling, you can now link your code with the SFML libraries you have built. This option is also applicable when you are using compilers other than those used to compile the available pre-built SFML libraries.

References:

- [1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/7119896/1116098
- [2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019